# Generate "special" getters and setters using Eclipse Templates

Tags: eclipse, templates

I´m trying to do a template that given some attributes generate "special" getters and setters for all the fields.

For example,

```
public class MyBean {

    private int numeric;
}
```

Generate this:

```
  public int getNumeric() {
    return numeric;
  }

  public void setNumeric(final int newNumeric) {
    this.numeric = newNumeric;
  }
```

I check that the default Eclipse template use the variable ${body_statement} to generate the setters and the getters, I think that I need to change this variable but I didn´t find the expression of this variable.

I try to use the following template but it doesn´t work correctly (I had to manually write the type and the field).

```
private ${type} get${field}() {return ${field};}

private void set${field}(final ${type} ${field}) {this.${field} = ${field};}
```

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could edit the template in  Java > Code Style > Code Templates or May be export the code template from Java > Code Style > Code Templates in eclipse and edit it the xml then could import back in.

Extract from code tempalte

```
<template autoinsert="true" context="setterbody_context"
        deleted="false" description="Code in created setters" enabled="true"        id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.codetemplates.setterbody"
 name="setterbody">${field} =       ${param};</template>
```

Java Editor Template Variables details are in following link
http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn´t work beacuse i would have to change the eclipse source to do my "special" getter... well maybe i´ll do it.

tks

Answer (score 0):

I think looking in Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates you will find in the Code section the getter body and setter body. Edit them there to include only the body you want (I assume you want to only customize the body).

Comment: Yes, i don´t want to change only the body. I want to to a getter (for example) with this aspect:
----------------------------------------------
public void setNumeric(final int newNumeric) {
    this.numeric = newNumeric;
  }
----------------------------------------------